# Nested logarithm and an inequality

Tags: derivatives, inequality, logarithms, lambert-w

I think it's hard but let me propose it :

> > Let $x\geq 0$ then we have :
> > $$\ln(\ln(\ln(\ln(\ln(\ln(\ln(\ln(x+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)\leq \operatorname{W}(\operatorname{W}(\operatorname{W}(\operatorname{W}(x))))$$

Where we speak about the Lambert's function .

To prove it I have tried to denest the logarithm since the inverse function of $f(x)=\ln(x+1)$ is $f^{-1}(x)=e^x-1$ it gives a nice power tower . Then I use the fact that :

$$\forall x>0\quad e^{\operatorname{W}(x)}=\frac{x}{\operatorname{W}(x)}$$

Wich is just the definition of the Lambert's function .

Unfortunately we can use it just one time and I got stuck here .

We can do the inverse and try to work with $p(x)=xe^x$ to eliminate the special function and keep just elementary function . Again we got a power tower but it's delicate to derivate it .

If you have a hint or a proof ...

...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $t \geqslant 1,$ because the function $t \mapsto 1/t$ is convex,
$$
\ln t \leqslant \frac{t - 1}2\left(1 + \frac1t\right) = \frac{t^2 - 1}{2t},
$$
therefore
$$
t\ln t \leqslant \frac{t^2 - 1}2 = (t - 1) + \frac{(t - 1)^2}2 \leqslant e^{t - 1} - 1 \quad (t \geqslant 1).
$$
Equivalently, because the function $t \mapsto e^{t - 1} - 1$ is strictly increasing on $[1, \infty),$
$$
(\ln(x + 1) + 1)\ln(\ln(x + 1) + 1) \leqslant x \quad (x \geqslant 0).
$$
Therefore $\ldots$

Comment: And then apply the definition of the Lambert's function ;-) Thanks it was funny !

Comment: I forgot to mention I was using the definition $\ln t = \int_1^t\frac{ds}s.$