# Stronger statement : $^{6}x\geq e^{\left(\frac{\ln^{2}\left(x+1\right)}{\ln\left(2\right)}-\ln\left(2\right)\right)}\geq \left(x^{2}+1\right)0.5$

Tags: inequality, power-towers

Let $x>0$ then  prove or disprove that :

$$x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x}}}}}\geq e^{\left(\frac{\ln^{2}\left(x+1\right)}{\ln\left(2\right)}-\ln\left(2\right)\right)}\geq \left(x^{2}+1\right)0.5$$

My attempt :

Claim :

Let $0<x\leq 1$ and $0<a<1$ and $f(x)=\ln\left(x^{x^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}}}\right)$ then :

$$f''(x)>0$$

Proof :

$$f''(x)= 2 a^{a^{a^a}} x^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}-2} - x^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}-2} + (a^{a^{a^{a}}} - 1) a^{a^{a^{a}}} x^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}-2} \ln(x)$$

It's straightforward since $$0.5\leq a^{a^{a^{a}}}\leq 1$$

So the function $e^{f(x)}$ is log concave it conducts to the inequality :

$$x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x}}}}}\geq 2\frac{\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^{2\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^{x^{x^{x^{x}}}}}}{y^{y^{x^{x^{x^{x}}}}}}$$

I'm stuck here...Perhaps we can show that the function $e^{f(x)}$ is strong log convex.

Edit 1

As the function seems to be strong log convex on $x,a\in(0,1]$ we have to show something like :

$$x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x}}}}}\geq\frac{\left(\frac{\left(x+a\right)}{2}\right)^{2\left(\frac{\left(x+a\right)}{2}\right)^{x^{x^{x^{x}}}}}}{a^{a^{x^{x^{x^{x}}}}}}e^{\left(\frac{1}{8}\cdot m\left(x-a\right)^{2}\right)}\geq^{?}e^{\left(\frac{\ln^{2}\left(x+1\right)}{\ln\left(2\right)}-\ln\left(2\right)\right)}$$

Where $$f''(x)\geq 2m>0$$

Edit 2:

It seems that the function $f(x)$ for $a\in(0,1)$ and $x\in(0,2)$ is log convex .

Edit 3 : Some toughts :

Let $b=x^{x^{x^{x}}}=cst$ and  introduce the function :

$$h(y)=\frac{\left(\frac{\left(y+x\right)}{2}\right)^{2\left(\frac{\left(y+x\right)}{2}\right)^{b}}}{y^{y^{b}}}$$

Then we compute the derivative :

$$h'(y)=u(y) (y (x + y)^b (b \ln(\frac{y + x}{2}) + 1) - (y + x) y^b (b \ln(y) + 1))$$

Then if $y+x\geq 1$ the derivative is positive and equal to zero if $y=x$

It's trivial remarking that :

$$(y + x) y^b\geq(y + x) y=(y + x) y\geq y (x + y)^b$$

And $u(y)>0$

Now if $x\leq y $ we have :

$$0.5x^2+0.5\leq 0.5y^2+0.5\leq^{?}h(y)$$

$$t(y)=\frac{\left(\frac{\left(x+y\right)}{2}\right)^{2\left(\frac{\left(x+y\right)}{2}\right)^{x^{x^{x^{x}}}}}}{y^{y^{x^{x^{x^{x}}}}}}-0.5y^{2}-0.5$$

$t(y)$ is a concave function for $x,y\in(0,1)$

Edit 5 :

An interesting inequality is :

$$\frac{\left(\frac{\left(x+a\right)}{2}\right)^{2\left(\frac{\left(x+a\right)}{2}\right)^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}}}}{x^{x^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}}}}\geq\frac{\left(\frac{\left(x+a\right)}{2}\right)^{2\left(\frac{\left(x+a\right)}{2}\right)^{a}}}{x^{x^{a}}}$$

For $1\geq x\geq a>0.5$ wich matchs partially with our problem.

Edit 6:We have the inequality for $x\geq a\geq 0.5$:
$$x^{a^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}}}\geq \left(x+x^{a^{\left(1+a\right)}}\right)0.5$$

Question:

How to show the first inequality ?

Any ideas is welcome !

Reference :

[About the inequality $x^{x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}} \ge \frac12 x^2 + \frac12$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4165595/about-the-inequality-xxxxxx-ge-frac12-x2-frac12/4165708#4165708)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126591/discussion-on-question-by-erik-satie-stronger-statement-6x-geq-e-left-f).