# Sharp bounds for power towers $x^x,x^{x^{x^x}},x^{x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}},\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, upper-lower-bounds, tetration

I am looking for a reference to results on sharp upper and lower bounds for the $2n$th power towers $$x^x,x^{x^{x^x}},x^{x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}},x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}}}},\cdots$$ over the intervals $x\in[0,1]$ and/or $[1,\infty)$ for any natural number $n$, such that the bounds contain exponent terms stacked no higher than the form $a^b$.

An example would be the inequality — valid for $[0,\infty)$: $$\frac12x^2+\frac12\le x^{x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}}$$ that has been [shown on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4165595/about-the-inequality-xxxxxx-ge-frac12-x2-frac12?noredirect=1&lq=1); however, this is for a specific $n=3$. I believe the case $x^x$ with $n=1$ is a bit better established, where we can derive lower bounds using Padé approximants, for instance.

Are there any papers that investigate this problem for this set of power towers?

Comment: Why is this interesting / what are the potential uses/applications of this?

Comment: @AdamRubinson A good answer to this post may help initiate an approach to [prove whether $\int_0^\infty dx/x^{x^{x^x}}<\int_0^\infty dx/x^{x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}}<\cdots$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417026). As for why I asked that MO question, I don't think it's just a coincidence that the sequence of integrals monotonically increases.

Comment: I would like to note that Donald E. Knuth and Rudy Rucker introduced a notation for such operations. (see [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation), [Rudy Rucker Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration), [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Notation))
This writing-style saves you a lot of work when writing these power towers.

Comment: For the $[1, \infty)$ lower bound, aren't you just looking for the lower bound to $x^x$ (since all higher towers are bigger?) Or is the formula allowed to contain $n$?

Comment: @AlexK Yes, both